# How can I customize tkinter dropdown menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a dropdown menu in tkinter of custom width and height and certain styling options like fore background etc. but when I am running my this code it is giving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'` and when I run my code without config it gives `'TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

These are my both two codes please help me in this problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root=Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')

seletion=StringVar()

def show():
    label=Label(root,text=seletion.get()).pack(pady=10)
   
drop=OptionMenu(root,seletion,'one','two','three',width=10).pack(pady=10)
button=Button(root,text='show',command=show).pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Second code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root=Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')

seletion=StringVar()

def show():
    label=Label(root,text=seletion.get()).pack(pady=10)
    pass

drop=OptionMenu(root,seletion,'one','two','three').pack(pady=10)
button=Button(root,text='show',command=show).pack(pady=10)
drop.config(width=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: if you really want to keep it in one line check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782288/14531062) from the same question

Comment: I think you are better off customizing the `ComboBox` widget from `ttk` as for example `OptionMenu` doesn't have `width` argument (you can still probably pack or grid it so that it fills the container on x axis), also do not import everything from a module (do not use `*` (wildcard) when importing modules)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to alter `OptionMenu` attributes including width and height as well as color, font and menu position.

It would probably be better to use `ttk.ComboBox` however to answer your question I will post this code.

Included is a function called `find` that will extract all attributes and their values from `tkinter` objects and display them in a human friendly way.

You can also display an image or bitmap so I've imported `filedialog` to assist with image selection.

This is your program with errors removed and extra code for attribute testing.

```py
def find( obj ):
    name = f"{type(obj).__name__}:\n    "
    try:
        return name + "\n    ".join( [ f"{x} = '{obj.cget(x)}'" for x in obj.keys() if x not in ['bg', 'fg', 'bd']] )
    except:
        return f"'{obj}' has no keys attribute"


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('500x500')

selection = tk.StringVar()

def show():
    label["text"] = selection.get()

label = tk.Label(root,text = selection.get())
label.pack()

drop = tk.OptionMenu(root,selection,'one','two','three')
drop.pack(pady = 10)


# Extra controls


image = fido.askopenfilename(title = "Choose a Picture")

if image:
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = image)
    photo_wide = photo.width()
    photo_high = photo.height()
    drop.config(height = photo_high, width = photo_wide,
                takefocus = 1, image = photo, compound = "center")
else:
    drop["height"] = '2'
    drop['width'] = '10'

drop["direction"] = ["above", "below", "flush", "left", "right"][2]
drop["anchor"] = ["n", "ne", "e", "se", "s", "sw", "w", "nw", "center"][0]
drop["justify"] = ["left", "right", "center"][1]
# drop["bitmap"] = "warning"
drop["background" ] = "cyan"
drop["activebackground" ] = "cyan"
drop["highlightbackground"] = "red"
drop["font"] = 'TkDefaultFont 14'

drop["menu"]["background"] = "red"
drop["menu"]["foreground"] = "yellow"
drop["menu"]["font"] = "TkDefaultFont 15"
drop["menu"]["selectcolor"] = "green"
drop["menu"]["activeborderwidth"] = '4'

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'show', command = show)
button.pack(pady = 10)

print(find( drop ))
print(find( drop[ "menu" ] ))

root.mainloop()
```